# Aptana Studio 3 doesn't recognize PHP inside .html

Tags: php, html, aptana, aptana3

When implementing code like i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DleAX.gif]

Next to `<?php` it gives red X icon with error that "<" missing '>' for end of tag. I did find some older threads about this here at stackoverflow, but there wasn't really any solution or response at all. I tried the solution of adding PHP Source Editor for .html and setting it as default, but looks like it doesn't work.

It's not a deal breaker, it's just I don't like red icons and false errors throughout the code.

Comment: This is a major bummer when you inherit a site built using html and want to convert it to php in phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question suggests that you are saving the files as .html

If this is the case then there will be an error as Aptana will not be looking to validate `<?php ?>` tags. If I'm right then you will need to save the files as `filename.php` and not `filename.html`.

If this is not the case then you might want to change the title slightly.

Comment: The question is talking about files with the suffix .html. So, the chosen answer appears to be: "Give up with trying to put PHP in .html files in Aptana Studio if you want to suppress warnings".

Answer (score 4):

This is because .html files are opened with HTML editor, not PHP.

You can try to right-click on your file, then select "Open With" -> "Other ..." -> "PHP Source Editor".

Comment: I tried that, errors doesn't disappear. Same in both HTML and PHP Editors.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag *is* legit html.  The file he's editing is html.  The stock html editor does not flag this as an error.  Sorry - I just joined and I can't "comment" yet - but my answer would be...

This looks like a bug in the Aptana HTML editor.

Comment: granted, but the engine is trying to parse HTML, and PHP isn't part of that spec.  HTML inside PHP is, which is why that works just fine with a '.php' extension.  but Apache won't parse PHP inside HTML at all (unless you do some horrible .htaccess chops), so my guess is Aptana is emulating that behaviour, which would be the right way to go if you're wanting an IDE that reflects how the server will interpret the document, if only in terms of neat colours.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I see this on occasion. If you're editing OPC (Other People's Code), especially WordPress code, sometimes an `IF` statement will be opened in one `PHP` file and closed in another. This is often seen in "the Loop" and is the way it's built.

Comment: Was there any particular reason that needed editing?